# Stored procedure to drop table

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure that will drop a table if it exists in a database. When running the stored procedure with EXEC, I am getting the following error:

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Procedure
>   sp_DropIfExists, Line 13 The name 'IF
>   EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE
>   OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'table_name')
>   AND type = (N'U')) DROP TABLE
>   [table_name]' is not a valid
>   identifier.

However if i copy and paste the T-SQL that is generated into management studio, it seems to be running fine. Can someone explain why this is not valid? The fix would be nice, but I am really after the Why primarily, The How would be nice to though! Thanks in advance.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DropIfExists](@tableName VARCHAR(255)) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @SQL = 'IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N''' + @tableName + ''') AND type = (N''U'')) DROP TABLE [' + @tableName + ']'
    PRINT @SQL;
    EXEC @SQL;
END
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use `sp_execute`

```
sp_executesql @SQL
```

for more information [msdn document link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: This worked out! Thanks for the help. Can you tell me why it did not work the way I had it?

Comment: Because t-sql try to find table which is not existing in sys.objects.
This is t-sql/mssql work way.

Comment: So if t-sql is looking for something that doesn't exist it would give an error of Invalid Identifier, and not Invalid object? That doesn't make much sense to me. Sorry if im reading into this to much, I am just trying to figure out why EXEC @foo would not work but EXEC sp_execsql @foo would?

Comment: Ah, forgot to add on this i did have to change the data type of @SQL from varchar to nvarchar.

Comment: `Since EXEC only permits string literals and string variables to be concatenated and not arbitrary expressions, this is not legal:

EXEC('UPDATE STATISTICS ' + quotename(@tbl) + ' WITH FULLSCAN')` - grabbed from [paragraph from doc about dynamic sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#EXEC4)

Comment: @alexb - The OP does not call procedures in the `EXEC` statement, it's a simple concatenation literal strings and variables.

Answer (score 5):

```
--ALTER (if procedure exists)

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_dropifexists (@tableName VARCHAR(255))

AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @SQL = 'IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N''' + @tableName + ''') AND type = (N''U'')) DROP TABLE [' + @tableName + ']'

    --if write EXEC @SQL without parentheses  sql says Error: is not a valid identifier

    EXEC (@SQL);

END

--test procedure

exec sp_DropIfExists 'table'
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your post, please include how/why your post will solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will solve your problems but you would be better placing you check is a function like so

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TableExists] 
(
@TableName VarChar(100)
)  
    RETURNS BIT
AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @TableExists BIT

IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sysobjects a
          WHERE a.name =  @TableName
          AND a.xtype = 'U')
    SET @TableExists = 1
ELSE
    SET @TableExists = 0


RETURN @TableExists
END
```

Then you can use it as follows.

```
IF dbo.TableExists('[table_name]') = 1
     DROP TABLE [table_name]
```

Try this and let me know if you still get the same error.

Comment: I don't remember well and don't have acess to sql-server right now, but it's not allowed to access to DB objects from functions.

Comment: Great! Clean and fit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`EXEC @SQL` should be `EXEC (@SQL)`. (But [@maycil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046510/stored-procedure-to-drop-table/6046710#6046710)'s suggestion is correct too.)

Turns out, without the parentheses `@SQL`'s value is interpreted as the name of a stored procedure to execute, not as a script. (I didn't know that before, but I made a small test to verify that it is indeed so.)