# How to drop a table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am using following C# method to execute [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) queries:

```
public bool ExecuteQuery(String pQuery)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString");
    con.Open();

    SqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(pQuery, con, trans);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        trans.Commit();
        con.Close();
        trans.Dispose();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        trans.Rollback();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(exp.Message, "Error!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    return false;
}
```

When I pass this statement:

```
ExecuteQuery("DROP TABLE MyTable");
```

then the method returns true, which means it worked fine, but when I check [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server), `myTable` was not dropped. If I run the same statement in [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio), `MyTable` is dropped...

Where am I wrong?

Comment: best way to create a store procedure and call it in c#

Comment: Side note - you should look into disposing of your resources once you're done with them to avoid memory leaks (anything that implements IDisposable - some examples I see here are SqlConnection, SqlCommand and I believe SqlTransaction too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before answering your question, some comments:

- Avoid coding such operations using query text, this is a high chance you can get problems with security. Better create stored procedure that [executes table drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046510/stored-procedure-to-drop-table):

  ```
  create procedure sp_DropTable
  @tablename varchar(200)
  as
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);
      SET @SQL = 'IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N''' + @tableName + ''') AND type = (N''U'')) DROP TABLE [' + @tableName + ']'

      EXEC (@SQL);
     END
  GO
  ```

Then pass the stored procedure's name as parameter to your function. Now back to your error.

Table drop is not a [transaction](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm), but you try to execute it in transactional schema. This makes it fail. Try:

```
public bool ExecuteQuery(String pQuery)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString");
    con.Open();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(pQuery, con);

        // if you pass just query text
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        // if you pass stored procedure name
        // cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;   

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(exp.Message, "Error!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: the sp will throw error. `incorect syntax near @tblename`

Comment: 1+ for updation in answer

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that was noobish of me really :/

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Is the stored procedure here susceptible to code injection?